# jQuery: clone div multiple times on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to figure out how to repeatedly clone the contents of a div on scroll, thus giving the impression that the page goes on forever and ever. My markup thus far is as follows and a fiddle here too https://jsfiddle.net/guht49La/:

```
var inserated = false
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 800 && inserated == false) {
    var $button = $('.hd').clone();
    ($button).insertBefore('.ap');
    inserated = true;
  } else {

  }
});
```

Although this only inserts it once, as I want to keep inserting it every 800px (for example) thus giving the impression that the page goes on forever and ever. Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you set `inserted` to `false`? If not, you need to set it after scrolling 800px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  will work

```
var inserated = false
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 800) {
    var $button = $('.hd').clone();
    ($button).insertBefore('.ap');
    inserated = true;
  } else {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete guess, but perhaps give this a go:

```
var nextInsert = 800;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= nextInsert) {
    var $button = $('.hd').clone();
    ($button).insertBefore('.ap');
    nextInsert += 800;
  } else {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but it clones the `div` just once because you changed the `inserated` variable to true after inserting the first clone. It will work indefinitely if you delete it:

```
var inserated = false
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 800 && inserated == false) {
    var $button = $('.hd').clone();
    ($button).insertBefore('.ap');
    // inserated = true;
  } else {

  }
});
```

Notice that `inserated = true;` is commented out.

That code, however, can (and almost certainly) creates a huge amount of clones, so I'd suggest controlling the scrolling insertion point using something along the lines of [Nat Karmios answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34566510/3397274)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is similar to [jbmartinez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34566510/1249442) answer, except I would drop the `inserated` variable altogether and use classes to determine elements to be cloned:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 800) {
    var $button = $('.hd').not(".cloned").clone();
    $button.addClass("cloned");
    ($button).insertBefore('.ap');
  } else {

  }
});
```

Would still need to adjust the scrolling mark as noted above tho.